# parse draftjs in Java

Tags: java, draftjs

I'm storing documents in the draftjs json format.

I now need to parse the draftjs in Java to send system emails from a java server.

Is there anyway to parse the draftjs to constuct html emails in Java?

I've searched for libraries but can't find any projects.

Is the only alternative to store them as html?

Comment: React's `server-side-rendering` should be the way I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and would recommend using [draft-convert](https://github.com/HubSpot/draft-convert) to **export** to HTML from the Draftjs JSON format

My experience is that since the official data conversion utility doesn't allow any customization, I've tried [draft-js-import-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/draft-js-import-html) and `draft-js-export-html` but couldn't get our customized blocks to work with it